# Regex to find positive & negative numbers + expressions

Tags: java, regex, file, text

I'm looking for regex to find positive & negative numbers + any expressions in a text file. Here is what I've currenly done:

```
public class EquationsTextExtractor implements RegexTextExtractor{
@Override
public List<String> extract(String source) {
    List<String> equations = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\s*[+\\-*/]\\s*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(source);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        equations.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return equations;
}
```

}

The current output is:

```
[02-495, 00-120, 2 + 2]
```

The desired output is:

```
 2 + 2, -5.4 / -3.33
```

Here is sample text:

```
This is an example source in which a person with the PESEL number 12345678901 came to a course with a person with the PESEL number 09876543211. This course took place at the address Warszawa 02-495 Orląt Lwowskich street, although originally they wanted to do it at 00-120 Złota 44, but the place ended, at the course they did arithmetic operations, the first example was solving 2 + 2, but then we moved on to negative numbers and it was -5.4 / -3.33 and it got a little harder.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*expressions*"? Does that eintail expressions with multiple operators and multiple layers of parenthesis (e.g. `((1 +2) * 3) / 4`)?

Comment: I believe its only going to be something simple such as 2 + 2 / 6 * 7 etc. Although if you have something in mind could you present regex for both? ((1 +2) * 3) / 4) as well as 2 + 2 ||  6 * 7? 

Thanks!

Comment: Why is `12345678901` not to be matched, but e.g. `2 + 2` is? Do you mean: There MUST be an operator (`+` is an operator) involved? Why is `02-495` not okay, but `2 - 495` should be matched? What specific part of it do you want to encode in your regex? The lack of spaces around the operator? The fact that the 02 starts with a 0? It sounds like what you want is utterly impossible, there's no way to tell the difference.

Comment: @rzwitserloot 12345678901 is a PESEL number & a different extractor is used for that. No there should be any operator involved such as +/-/*//

Comment: @rzwitserloot so 02-495 is a Polish post code & for that ive got a different extractor where the regex for that is: \d{2}-\d{3}

I believe its only has to be something simple such as 2 * 2 / 2 + 2 rather than big numbers as youve mentioned 2 - 495

Comment: @RonielLópez Thank you this is working now :) Could you share with me how you created this regex? Did you use some kind of generator or how did you come about coming up with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will give you the desired output:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?\s+[*/+-]\s+[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?![a-zA-Z])
```

but there will be some scenarios not covered

Note: to obtain this regular expression I started working with your regular expression and changing things to obtain the desired output